# Git : Could not read from remote repository when pushing

Tags: git

Everything worked fine until today, trying to push my changes to one of the remote servers and encounter this error

```
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: retry: No child processes
/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

That one of repos poses problem because others work until now well.

Which lets me deduce that the problem comes from the remote repository

Have you on idea ?

Comment: The fact that you're seeing "No child processes" from `/etc/profile.d/locallib.sh` seems like you may have put something in place that is causing a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).